# Why is the conditional probability not working for `CategoricalDistribution`?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions

**Bug introduced in 12.1 and fixed in 12.3**

---

Consider the following simple example for demonstration:

```
Probability[
    result=="Win"\[Conditioned]weather=="Fair",
    {weather,result}\[Distributed]CategoricalDistribution[
        {{"Rain","Fair"},{"Win","Lose"}},
        {{0.4,0.4},{0.12,0.08}}
    ]
]
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax? Is it a bug?

Comment: Did you try using `NProbability[]` instead?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, `NProbability` is also not working. I think WRI forgot to implement conditional probability for `CategoricalDistribution`. Should I add the tag bug on it?

Comment: That definitely sounds reportable to Support.

Comment: @J.M. have you updated to 12.3? Can you check if it is working in 12.3?

Comment: I can access 12.3 in the cloud, and it seems both `Probability[]` and `NProbability[]` can handle it now.

Answer (score 8):

I think your syntax is just fine.  `Probability` just doesn't know how to do it.

The brute force way, of course, is the following:

```
cd = CategoricalDistribution[{{"Rain", "Fair"}, {"Win", "Lose"}}, {{0.4, 0.4}, {0.12, 0.08}}];
Probability[result == "Win" && weather == "Fair", {weather, result} \[Distributed] cd]/
  Probability[weather == "Fair", {weather, result} \[Distributed] cd]
(* 0.6 *)
```

Comment: Have you updated to 12.3? Can you check if it is working in 12.3? Have they added the definitions of conditional probability in `Probability` and `NProbability`?

Answer (score 7):

```
cd = CategoricalDistribution[{{"Rain", "Fair"}, {"Win", "Lose"}}, 
  {{0.4, 0.4}, {0.12, 0.08}}];
```

**Update:** Again using simple queries we can get two tables of conditional probabilities as `Dataset` objects

```
probtable = Information[cd, "ProbabilityTable"];

condProbResultGivenWeather = probtable[All, Normalize[#, Total] &];

condProbWeatherGivenResult = probtable[Transpose][All, Normalize[#, Total] &];

Row[{condProbResultGivenWeather, condProbWeatherGivenResult}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
condProbResultGivenWeather["Fair", "Win"]
```

> ```
> 0.6
> ```

```
condProbResultGivenWeather[All, "Win"]
```

[image]

```
condProbResultGivenWeather["Fair"]
```

[image]

```
condProbWeatherGivenResult["Win", "Fair"]
```

> ```
> 0.230769
> ```

```
condProbWeatherGivenResult[All, "Fair"]
```

[image]

```
condProbWeatherGivenResult["Win"]
```

[image]

#### Information + "ProbabilityTable"

Using [`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html) we get the joint probability table as a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)  object. We then can get the conditional probabilities using simple queries:

```
probtable = Information[cd, "ProbabilityTable"]
```

[image]

Conditional probability of `"Win"` given `"Fair"`:

```
probtable["Fair", #Win / Total @ # &]
```

> ```
> 0.6
> ```

Conditional probability of `"Fair"` given `"Win"`:

```
probtable[#Fair / Total @ # &, "Win"]
```

> ```
> 0.230769
> ```

#### PDF + MarginalDistribution

We can also use the functions `PDF` and `MarginalDistribution` to get the same result:

```
PDF[cd, {"Fair", "Win"}] / PDF[MarginalDistribution[cd, 1], "Fair"]
```

> ```
> 0.6
> ```

```
 PDF[cd, {"Fair", "Win"}] / PDF[MarginalDistribution[cd, 2], "Win"]
```

> ```
> 0.230769
> ```